# In Android project include another project

Tags: java, android

I'm just starting my long way to Android programming and building app where I would like to use this library https://github.com/cfgxy/DevsmartLib-Android/tree/

This is another Android project, how should I include this in my project using Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of that repo's `devsmartlib/` directory appears to be an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects). You can use such projects [from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) or [from the command line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Android project in Eclipse and select the contents of `devsmartlib/` as the source folder.

You can then right click on your project, click Properties, Android and add the library project from there!